# Format input in angular

Tags: angular, input, format

I want to have an input field in Angular 2 which has the following format for numbers greater than 1.000. Basically I want to format the number as 1.000,00. Does anybody know how?

Comment: Is this your requirement? https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/inputmask

Comment: I think filters is what you are looking for. Number filters to be more precice. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/number

Comment: @NikhilSahu that link is for a different framework. How about this https://angular.io/api/common/formatNumber